# Tableau - Ignore zero values from percentage table calculation

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table of monthly figures, split out by year:
[image]

I want to do a percentage calculation to show the monthly YoY values like this:

[image]

However, for months where there is no data, i.e. November and December 2017, it shows -100%.

Is there a way to ignore these values in the calculation? Ideally a way that will automatically update (as this is going to be published).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there should be a table calc option for this, and there may be one I'm not aware of, but I was able to put together a calculated field to accomplish this.

```
IF ZN(SUM([Amount])) = 0
OR ZN(LOOKUP(SUM([Amount]), -1)) = 0
THEN NULL
ELSE
(ZN(SUM([Amount])) / ZN(LOOKUP(SUM([Amount]), -1))) - 1
END
```